# ionic Android build problem - transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play-services

After I install batch push notification Cordova plugin to my ionic app, I can't build android. When I run `ionic cordova run android` it shows this errors:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED
35 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 34 up-to-date
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\32.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\29.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\17.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\16.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\35.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\32.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\10.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\39.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\36.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\33.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\30.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\20.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\19.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\2.jar --input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\30.jar 
--output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\27.jar 
--input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\36.jar --output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\33.jar --input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\7.jar --input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\1 --input C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\23.jar --output C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\21.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\17.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\18.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\19.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\20.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\22.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\23.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\24.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\25.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\26.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\27.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\28.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\30.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\31.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\32.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\33.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\34.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\35.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\36.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\37.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\38.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\39.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\40.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\43.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\repos\0ccrs\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\44.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 19 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

It's worked until yesterday and I built it several time. but today it did not work by itself!
I searched but I could not resolve problem. I understand that the problem can be two things interacting or conflict. one of them can be `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:+"` in `batch.gradle` file.
I don't have any idea! please help me.
my versions:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.6.0
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
NodeJS            : v6.9.5 
npm               : 3.10.10
```

How I can do?

Comment: I have the same exact problem that I am currently trying to fix, cordova-google-plus and cordova-admob-plugin toghether raise the issue.

The only way to successfully build again is to remove the platform ( I use 7.1.4 as well ) and then one of the plugin and add again the platform.I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo I didn't install cordova-google-plus or cordova-admob-plugin. I only install batch push notification plugin. check this link, It may work for you:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this evening

Comment: Tested the plugin with different play version, I get another error. Cordova is a nice tool but is a serious configuration hell. Everything may stop working at some point and you get stuck. Anyway, thank you for the advice!

Comment: Wait, without that I changed absolutely anything, I give it again a couple of build try and the build succeed and all the plugin that I've installed works toghether. This was the error I got before the correct build:

:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files

So, thank you again

Comment: If you install `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` plugin and build your app, it downloads some source for other versions compatibility. if do it once it is enough and every thing you need already downloaded. maybe you need `cordova clead` too.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo yes I used this 2 cordova plugins and I solved issue: `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` and `cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release`. you should use `cordova clean` too.

1) I find conflict versions first in the errors (I needed v11.0.4 but it installs v15.0.0 too). 2) then I change `cordova-android-firebase-gradle-releas` manualy in it `.gradle` file to install this version and I run `ionic cordova run android` and it download version 11.0.4 too. 3) then I install `play-services` plugin too. 4) then I run `cordova clean`. It solved.